# Number of lattice paths from $(1,1)$ to $(m,n)$ when unit moves east and north are allowed.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider a robot moving in an $m \times n$ grid, where $m \le n$. It starts at the coordinate $(1, 1)$. At each step, when it is at position $(i, j)$, it either moves one square up to $(i + 1, j)$ (assuming that $i < m$) or one square right to $(i, j + 1)$ (assuming that $j < n$). How many different ways can the robot travel from $(1, 1)$ to $(m, n)$?

Would you please Justify your answer.

Comment: Where is the measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** there are $m-1$ steps to the east and $n-1$ steps to the north. They can be placed in any order with respect to each other. Consider writing each path as a sequence of $m-1$ E's and $n-1$ N's in the order in which each step is taken.

Comment: do you mind if you explain more?!

Comment: Since this looks as if it might be a homework problem, I only want to provide a hint. Wherever the problem came from should talk about combinatorics and how to solve such problems. If not, look up [Combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) and [Combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) in Wikipedia.